# Aligning children of two flexbox containers

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to create two flexbox containers with children items, and the second container has a subset of children of the first one, but I want that they widths aligns with the above ones. The children uses width and flex to adjust, but since the second container has less children, they actual width doesn't match. Look at this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBgKmR

I can't just put more items in the second container to fill in the html. I need something like setting a property of flex-container which declare they children widths.

Is something like that possible?

Here is the codepen content:

```css
    .flex-container {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .item {
      padding: 5px;
      height: 150px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      
      line-height: 150px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 3em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .flex-item {
      background: tomato;
      flex: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="flex-container">
      <li class="item flex-item">1</li>
      <li class="item flex-item">2</li>
      <li class="item" style="background-color: green; width: 50px">3</li>
      <li class="item flex-item">4</li>
      <li class="item flex-item">5</li>
      <li class="item flex-item">6</li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul class="flex-container">
      <li class="item flex-item">a</li>
      <li class="item flex-item">b</li>
      <li class="item" style="background-color: green; width: 50px">c</li>
      <li class="item flex-item">d</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: so the first one will have its children always stretched and the second one should follow? is the number fixed or not?

Comment: The first one should be as now. I want to tell the second container that it should calculate children items for "a" and "b" as the same width it calculated on the first container for "1" and "2".

Comment: no way with CSS only if the content is dynamic

Comment: The children of flex containers have no idea what children in other containers are doing. They have no association. They need to be *siblings* for their behaviors to match (using just CSS).

Answer (score 0):

Grid layout's `grid-template-columns` was what I really want and needed, a way to the parent declare children's widths.